# How to correctly implement push notifications using Gmail API

Tags: swift, api, push-notification, gmail

I've done all steps required and I'm successfully receive push notifications on my server endpoint. I want to get message text snippet and sender to be displayed in push notification but this requires a call to history API with valid user token. Moreover I want to filter this to push only new messages not all Inbox activity. In what way should I do this to provide safe experience. Should I store Gmail auth tokens on serverside and make calls from there and then push a notification with proper message data to users ? Is token storing and handling proper and safe on my server ? Or maybe there is another way ?